# How to group a unique column and find the mean value in a separate column in R

Tags: r, dataset, data-cleaning

My table of data looks like this image (but with many more lines):

[image]

I want to be able to find the mean age of each region, so the mean age for region SSC20790 and so on. I believe I can use the `dplyr` package?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this for instance:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(data,'region',function(x) {mean(x$age)})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the dplyr package can be used to calculate that:

```
mean_by_region <- your_data %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  mutate(mean_age=mean(age,na.rm=T)) %>%
  data.frame()
```